# Cycle and paste between workbooks with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I need to copy and paste the values from workbook 1 into workbook 2 if it says "yes" in the last column of workbook1.

I then need to cycle to the next row in workbook 1 and paste the values into a NEW worksheet in workbook 2 and do the same until it no longer says "yes" in the last column of workbook 1.

I have the following code so far. How do I loop between the rows in workbook 1?

```
Dim InputFile As Workbook
Dim OutputFile As Workbook
'other code here not relevant 
Set InputFile = Workbooks.Open(filepath)
Set OutputFile = ThisWorkbook

Dim Lastname As String
Dim Firstname As String
Dim InvEntityname As String
Dim Commitment As Long
Dim InvoiceAmount As Long

Dim Col As Range

For Each Col In Range("U5", Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If Col.Value = "Yes" Then

        Lastname = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)
        Firstname = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1)
        InvEntityname = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2)
        Commitment = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 6)
        InvoiceAmount = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 15)

 ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
        Range("c24") = Lastname
        Range("D24") = Firstname
        Range("B13") = InvEntityname
        Range("E41") = Commitment
        Range("G41") = InvoiceAmount

End If
    Next Col

ActiveSheet.Name = Range("b13")
Worksheets.Copy After:=ActiveSheet
```

Comment: First, change `ActiveCell` to `Col`. Second, I would suggest to qualify all your `Range` variable to make a picture clear (which avoids selections).

Comment: <For Each Col In Range("U5" & ":" & Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address)>. You have assigned ThisWorkbook to OutPutFile. Why aren't you using it then? You should lose the '.Activate' and put ','s infront of the following 'Range's. It is unclear from which sheet the e.g. Lastname variable gets its value.

Answer (score 1):

## Rows To Sheets

Since there is much guessing here involved be careful how to use it not to lose data.

This code opens a workbook and on its Activesheet loops through the U column and each time it finds "Yes", from the found row, copies some cells to ThisWorkbook's first (1) sheet, then creates a copy of the sheet right after it and renames the copy; thus creating as many worksheets as found "Yes"-es.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RowsToSheets()

  Dim wsInput As Worksheet
  Dim Col As Range

  'other code here not relevant

  Set wsInput = Workbooks.Open(filepath).ActiveSheet

  For Each Col In wsInput.Range("U5" & ":" _
      & wsInput.Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address)

    If Col.Value = "Yes" Then

      With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

        ' Copy data from found row to ws.
        .Range("C24") = Col.Offset(1, 0)   ' Lastname
        .Range("D24") = Col.Offset(1, 1)   ' Firstname
        .Range("B13") = Col.Offset(1, 2)   ' InvEntityname
        .Range("E41") = Col.Offset(1, 6)   ' Commitment
        .Range("G41") = Col.Offset(1, 15)  ' InvoiceAmount

        ' Create a copy after itself.
        .Copy after:=.Parent.Worksheets(1)

'        ' I Would prefer here after the last worksheet: 
'        .Copy after:=.Parent.Worksheets(.Parent.Worksheets.Count)
'        ' Rename the copy.
'        .Parent.Worksheets(.Parent.Worksheets.Count).Name = .Range("B13")     

        ' Rename the copy.
        .Parent.Worksheets(.Index + 1).Name = .Range("B13")

      End With

    End If

  Next

  Set Col = Nothing
  Set wsInput = Nothing

End Sub
```